# DataBinding not working

Tags: xml, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows Phone app.

I have the following C# code:

```
private void Default_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    long gameId;
    short gameType;
    loadedData = XDocument.Load("SampleData/GamesDesc.xml");
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.Count == 2)
    {
        if (long.TryParse(NavigationContext.QueryString.Values.First(), out gameId))
        {
            if (short.TryParse(NavigationContext.QueryString.Values.Last(), out gameType))
            {
                var filteredData = from c in loadedData.Descendants("gameDescription")
                    where c.Attribute("game_id").Value == gameId.ToString() &&
                            c.Attribute("gameType").Value == gameType.ToString() &&
                            c.Attribute("language").Value.Equals(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
                    select new SampleData.GameDesc()
                    {
                        Id = uint.Parse(c.Attribute("game_id").Value),
                        Name = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                        Language = c.Attribute("language").Value,
                        GameType = uint.Parse(c.Attribute("gameType").Value),
                        ShortDescription = c.Attribute("shortDescription").Value,
                        LongDescription = c.Attribute("longDescription").Value
                    };

                LayoutRoot.DataContext = filteredData;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the following XAML code:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid x:Name="LongDescPanel" Margin="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.45*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.55*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="LongDescription" Margin="8,8,8,13" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LongDescription}"/>
            <Button x:Name="PlayButton" Content="{Binding Path=AppResources.Play, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="165,36,165,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Grid.Row="1" Click="PlayButton_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Why `LongDescription` TextBlock does show nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting an `IEnumberable<SampleData.GameDesc>` as *LayoutRoot*'s *DataContext*. That is why it fails to read a property named *LongDescription* on it.

Try setting single element as *DataContext*:

```
LayoutRoot.DataContext = filteredData.First();
```

If you want to display all items and not just first one, use an *ItemsControl*.